# Best deployment alternative for Azure App Service

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, deployment, azure-web-app-service

We have an ASP.net Core application that we deploy in multiple Azure App Service using old-fashioned FTP deployment.

We want to know if there is an advantage in building Docker containers and deploy that instead. Do they consume more or less memory on the server? Is there a trade-off for choosing one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is multi dimensional. Lets see the Docker and Kubernetes dimension first as you seem to be more interested in that.  Docker and Kubernetes are suitable for Microservices architecture. Memory consumption is not a factor that you should consider when choosing Docker and Kube. Docker and Kube are two different services. Docker is container technology and Kubernetes is container orchestration technology. i.e. It manages container instances. In short hey are not deployment solutions. Using docker will not automatically make your application efficient in terms or memory and cpu utilization. If you are not using Azure DevOps Pipelines, I would recommend using Build and Release pipelines tasks to do your build and deploy your .net core application.